# How do you extract only the uppercase portions of a string in Stata?

Tags: regex, string, stata, uppercase

Here's a sample of the data:

```
part1
"Cambridge, Maryland TEST MODEL SEADROME"
"L.B. MAYER HONORED"
"A TOWN MOVES"
"U.S. SAVINGS BONDS RALLY"
"N.D. NOSES OUT S.M.U. BY 27 TO 20"
"Philadelphia, Pa. BURN 2,300 SQUEALERS"
"Odd Bits In To-day's News"
"Saratoga Springs, N.Y. DIAVOLO IS STAR AT BRILLIANT SPA OPENING"
"Risk Death in Daring Race"
"Philadelphia, PA. IT'S HIGHER EDUCATION"
"806 DECORATIONS"
"Snow Hauled 20 Miles For Skiers"
"F.D.R. ASKS VICTORY EFFORT"
```

Each string either has an upper and lowercase portion, or is all uppercase. I've been trying to use regular expressions to extract only the uppercase portions of the string, but haven't had any luck. The best I've been able to do is identify when a string starts or ends with a certain number of uppercase characters:

```
generate title = regexs(0) if regexm(part1, "^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$")
```

I've also tried the following, which I pulled from another question in the forum:

```
generate title = regexs(0) if(regexm(part1, "\b[A-Z]{2,}\b"))
```

Which is supposed to look for words with at least two uppercase letters in a row, but it only returns missing values for me. I'm using Stata version 13.1 for Mac.

Comment: Not sure what you want: get segments with all uppercase letters? Try using `^[^a-z]+$`. However, negated classes may not be supported. If it does not work, you will have to try workarounds like `^[A-Z][0-9A-Z~\`@#$%^&*()_+ '=\]\[{}\\|'";:/?,.><-]+$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stribizhev points out, *negation* may be a way:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str70 myvar
"Cambridge, Maryland TEST MODEL SEADROME"
"L.B. MAYER HONORED"
"A TOWN MOVES"
"U.S. SAVINGS BONDS RALLY"
"N.D. NOSES OUT S.M.U. BY 27 TO 20"
"Philadelphia, Pa. BURN 2,300 SQUEALERS"
"Odd Bits In To-day's News"
"Saratoga Springs, N.Y. DIAVOLO IS STAR AT BRILLIANT SPA OPENING"
"Risk Death in Daring Race"
"Philadelphia, PA. IT'S HIGHER EDUCATION"
"806 DECORATIONS"
"Snow Hauled 20 Miles For Skiers"
"F.D.R. ASKS VICTORY EFFORT"
end

gen title = trim(regexs(2)) if regexm(myvar, "([,.]*)([^a-z]*$)")

list title
```

The result is

```
. list title

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |                                         title |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. |                           TEST MODEL SEADROME |
  2. |                            L.B. MAYER HONORED |
  3. |                                  A TOWN MOVES |
  4. |                      U.S. SAVINGS BONDS RALLY |
  5. |             N.D. NOSES OUT S.M.U. BY 27 TO 20 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  6. |                          BURN 2,300 SQUEALERS |
  7. |                                               |
  8. | N.Y. DIAVOLO IS STAR AT BRILLIANT SPA OPENING |
  9. |                                               |
 10. |                     PA. IT'S HIGHER EDUCATION |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
 11. |                               806 DECORATIONS |
 12. |                                               |
 13. |                    F.D.R. ASKS VICTORY EFFORT |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

I think that's close to what you want, but not perfect. It's difficult to imagine a straightforward method to cleanup strings if they don't have some regular structure. Compare the input/output of observations 6 and 10, for example.

If you have a titles database, after an initial cleanup, you can compare and match with that. See `ssc describe strgroup`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The implication of the question seems to be that you expect a regular expression specification to pull out all instances. However reasonable that might be, it's not how regular expressions work in Stata. You need a loop over instances. This uses `moss` (`ssc install moss`), which has that as its main purpose. (The hint of gathering moss is typical feeble wordplay from the second program author concerned, if he is reading this.)

```
clear 
input str100 part1
"Cambridge, Maryland TEST MODEL SEADROME"
"L.B. MAYER HONORED"
"A TOWN MOVES"
"U.S. SAVINGS BONDS RALLY"
"N.D. NOSES OUT S.M.U. BY 27 TO 20"
"Philadelphia, Pa. BURN 2,300 SQUEALERS"
"Odd Bits In To-day's News"
"Saratoga Springs, N.Y. DIAVOLO IS STAR AT BRILLIANT SPA OPENING"
"Risk Death in Daring Race"
"Philadelphia, PA. IT'S HIGHER EDUCATION"
"806 DECORATIONS"
"Snow Hauled 20 Miles For Skiers"
"F.D.R. ASKS VICTORY EFFORT"
end 
compress 

moss part1, match("([A-Z]+)") regex 
egen wanted = concat(_match*), p(" ")
l wanted

     +--------------------------------------------------+
     |                                           wanted |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  1. |                          C M TEST MODEL SEADROME |
  2. |                                L B MAYER HONORED |
  3. |                                     A TOWN MOVES |
  4. |                          U S SAVINGS BONDS RALLY |
  5. |                        N D NOSES OUT S M U BY TO |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  6. |                               P P BURN SQUEALERS |
  7. |                                        O B I T N |
  8. | S S N Y DIAVOLO IS STAR AT BRILLIANT SPA OPENING |
  9. |                                          R D D R |
 10. |                       P PA IT S HIGHER EDUCATION |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
 11. |                                      DECORATIONS |
 12. |                                        S H M F S |
 13. |                        F D R ASKS VICTORY EFFORT |
     +--------------------------------------------------+
```

I've assumed that you want spaces between the results; it's hardly intelligible otherwise. You don't specify punctuation between upper case; if you want that, you will need to modify the regular expression accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single rule that will cleanly parse with a single command this type of data. Often, the best strategy is to target the easy cases then move on to more difficult cases until diminishing returns makes additional attempts unappealing.

It's important to pay attention to unintended matches when using regular expressions, particularly if the number of observations is large. I use `listsome` (from SSC) for this type of work.

It looks like `part1` often starts with a city name followed by a State name/abbreviation. Here's code that handles the easy cases and the city/state cases:

```
clear
input str60 part1
"Cambridge, Maryland TEST MODEL SEADROME" 
"L.B. MAYER HONORED" 
"A TOWN MOVES" 
"U.S. SAVINGS BONDS RALLY" 
"N.D. NOSES OUT S.M.U. BY 27 TO 20" 
"Philadelphia, Pa. BURN 2,300 SQUEALERS" 
"Odd Bits In To-day's News" 
"Saratoga Springs, N.Y. DIAVOLO IS STAR AT BRILLIANT SPA OPEN" 
"Risk Death in Daring Race" 
"Philadelphia, PA. IT'S HIGHER EDUCATION" 
"806 DECORATIONS" 
"Snow Hauled 20 Miles For Skiers" 
"F.D.R. ASKS VICTORY EFFORT" 
end

* take care of the easy cases where there are no lowercase letters
gen title = part1 if !regexm(part1,"[a-z]")

* this type of string work is easier if text is aligned to the left
leftalign   // (from SSC)

* target cases of City, State at the start of part1.
* with complex patterns, it's easy to miss unintended matches when
* lots of obs are involved so use -listsome- (from SSC to track changes)
gen title0 = title
replace title = trim(regexs(3)) if regexm(part1,"^([A-Z][a-z ]*)+, ([A-Z][a-z]*\.?)+([^a-z]+$)")
listsome if title != title0

list part1 title
```